# How to uninstall ASUS ATK package?

Tags: windows-8.1, uninstall, asus-laptop

I ran "Decrap My PC" on a new laptop. After restarting, I got the warning `4PG This program can only be executed on the Asus computer.`

I googled this and the only suggestion I found was [reinstalling the ATK package](http://forum.notebookreview.com/asus/688162-atk0100-asus.html).

So I downloaded it but when I tried to install it, an error came up that **it can't be installed because it already has been installed**.

So I want to uninstall and reinstall it but I can't find it. After searching my `C` drive, I did find an ATK folder in `C:\eSupport\eDriver\Software\ASUS` so I removed that but this didn't solve the problem.

What could I try next?

Comment: Is this a laptop? If so, the ATK Package is one thing you probably want to keep. Uninstalling it will disable the "Fn" key and all of the secondary functions.

Comment: @PeterFitzgerald: yes, it's a laptop. I'm trying to **reinstall** the ATK Package but I can't since it already is installed.

Comment: Is the ATK Package not listed in the list of Programs and Features in the Control Panel?

Comment: No, there's only 'Windows Driver Package [...]' and I assume it's not a good idea to uninstall that.

Comment: The ATK folder located in C:\eSupport\eDriver\Software\ASUS contains the installer for the version that you DO want. If you were to delete anything, it would be the ATK folder located in C:\Program Files.

Comment: There is no ATK folder in `C:\Program Files\Asus`. Where exactly did you find it?

Comment: Try running the Asus automatic update program. It should detect the missing ATK driver and prompt you to restore it. I went through this same thing when trying to de-bloat my Asus Zenbook but I don't have it with me right now so I can't be too specific.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14332/discussion-between-rubengeert-and-peter-fitzgerald)

Answer (score 4):

I found a fix:

- Go to `C:\eSupport\eDriver\Software\ASUS`
- Enter ATK Package directory and find `setup.exe`
- Launch it, it asks whether to `repair or uninstall`: choose `uninstall`
- After this run, you must restart Windows
- Then, install the new ATK Package provided by ASUS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can add that when you are trying to install the new ATK Package for Windows 10 from downloaded from Asus it didn't give the option to uninstall. It just says that you have uninstall the previouos version installed using add/remove programs :/
Best regards

Comment: thanks for contributing. For me, however, the issue has long since been resolved. But perhaps others will find it useful anyway.

Comment: This also worked to just install the package when it was not installed on a fresh windows 10 boot

Answer (score 1):

Go into your device manager, right click on "Keyboard device filter" and open Properties. On the driver tab, you'll see that the driver provider is "ATK." First just try rolling back the driver to restore the correct version. If that doesn't work, use the uninstall button to remove the current version that isn't being properly recognized then try reinstalling the correct version.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A better solution:

Download the correct ASUS ATK package driver for your notebook and run the installer. 
If the package exists, it will give you the option to uninstall or repair. 
Select Uninstall and it will clean up the older ATK driver prior to upgrading to a newer one or completely uninstalling the package.

Note that you cannot install a newer ATK package over an older version. You MUST uninstall the older version FIRST using the method described here.

As of date, ASUS doesn't provide the installation entry in the Add/Remove programs section in the control panel.